# Create a view of four different yet similar tables in Oracle. What is the best way to do this?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, view

I have the following four different tables.

```
Param_SYSTEM (Name,Value,Type,Size,Filler)
Param_NodeId (Name,Value,Type,Size,NodeId,Filler)
Param_NodeTyp (Name,Value,Type,Size,NodeTyp,Filler)
Param_LRGRP (Name,Value,Type,Size,DataType,Qual1,Qual2)
```

Assume all items are VARCHAR.
May be size is INT

What I want is "UNION ALL" but if I understand correctly, that only works if all my table columns are one to one matching which is not the case here (see LRGGRP table)

Should I use Join instead?

Should I use a normal view or a materialized view?

Our data set is small (100k or so) and it is very important to get the latest data every time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use join if you need to display data in some relation. Use `union all` if you have unrelated sets of rows and you want to select them all in one statement.

If you are sure with `UNION ALL`, simply provide `NULL` value to columns, witch are no relevant in partial query:

```
create view param_vie (Name, Value, Type, Size, Filler, NodeId, NodeTyp, DataType, Qual1, Qual2) as
select Name,Value,Type,Size,Filler, null, null, null, null, null
  from Param_SYSTEM
union all
select Name,Value,Type,Size,Filler, NodeId, null, null, null, null
  from Param_NodeId
union all
select Name,Value,Type,Size,Filler, null, NodeTyp, null, null, null
  from Param_NodeTyp
union all
select Name,Value,Type,Size,Filler, null, null, DataType, Qual1, Qual2
  from Param_LRGRP
```

Comment: I like this answer. Will try and see if this works for me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too general to answer. However, even if you were to provide more information, the best answer to your question will probably end with a caveat that sounds something like this...

Whichever solutions you test, you will want to evaluate their respective merit based on at least these variables: (a) ease of maintenance, (b) response time, and (c) resource consumption.

The reason you may have to rigorously test all the solutions is that Oracle is far from simple and your information (including requirements) will change over time. Keeping test definitions and test outcomes is a valuable habit to get into.

In other words, what might be good for you in this specific instance might be horrible for someone (including your future self) who thinks they're in the same boat as you.